# how to solve NPM errno -4058

Tags: vue-cli

I'm using Node.js v20.3.0, npm: '9.6.7'.

I'm receiving the following error message while installing the vue cli(npm install -g @vue/cli)

```
C:\Users\USER>npm install -g @vue/cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\USER\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\Users\USER\'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-06-12T12_26_22_938Z-debug-0.log
```